# click for show google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have one page for show job pic and location . i want when page load first show job pic 
and when click on  map load instead of pic .

this is may code

```
<script>

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'onclick', initialize);
</script>

<div id="panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="england london">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress();">
</div>
<div  id="map-canvas"> <img src="img/src.jpg" /></div>
```

but when page load first map load and pic not show .

how i can use "button" to swich between image and map and first load image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *initializing* the **`geocoder`** variable ***within*** the `initialize()` method.  So you've call this method before the below method `geocoder.geocode(...)` like

```
function codeAddress() {
  initialize(); //intialize geocoder
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  ....
  ....
```

**FYI:** 
Also `map-canvas` element needs `height` and `width`.  So set styles like

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px:
}
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/y4AA6/)

**Note:**

or either call the **`initialize()`** at page load for better performance else each time the Google maps will be initialized.

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```